# Error in MS Access: Run-time Error '424': Object Required

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm currently making a button that is supposed to update a table with data from a subform (which is linked to another table). It is supposed to only take data of those records whose checkboxes (fldFlag) is checked by the user.

This is the code where I am having problems

```
If tblCoverageBatch.fldFlag = True Then
```

If it helps please find below the whole code

```vb
Private Sub CmdAssignSTOT_Click()
'Declarations
Dim ask As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
'popup message box to confirm save
ask = MsgBox("Do you want to save new STOT entry?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "System message...") = vbYes
    If ask = True Then
        'initialize value of incrementing variable x
        x = 0
        Set DB = CurrentDb
        Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("STOTCoverageBatchAssigned") 'setting the table
        Do While x < DCount("[ID]", "[STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned]") 'actions below to be performed until the last record
            If tblCoverageBatch.fldFlag = True Then 'actions below will only be performed when their tickbox fldFlag is ticked.
                With rst 'encoding!
                .Edit
                    ![STOTNo] = Me.STOTNo
                    ![STOTDate] = Me.STOTDate
                    ![BatchNo] = STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.BatchNo
                    ![PCICCheck] = STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.CompleteDocsPCIC
                    ![ARBCheck] = STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.CompleteDocsARB
                    ![PCICDocsReceivedDate] = STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.PCICDocsReceivedDate
                    ![ARBDocsReceivedDate] = STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.ARBDocsReceivedDate    
                .Update
                End With
                x = x + 1 'increment x by 1 to move on to the next record
            End If
        Loop
    Me.STOTNo.Value = Nz(DLast("STOTNo", "tblSTOT"), 0) + 1 'increment STOT number in the STOTNo field  only when actions above have been performed
    End If
End Sub`
```

Thank you!

Comment: At very top of VBA module outside of any subroutine or function, place `Option Explicit`. Then compile your code. Likely the issue is *STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned* and *tblCoverageBatch* objects which are never assigned in VBA but appears to be tables. Also, you are not walking through recordset properly as you never use *x* iterator variable. Please edit post to describe the relationships of these tables and what is on your form.

Comment: Can't reference table directly like that. Which record should value be pulled from? If you are cycling through recordset then reference the recordset object. `If rst.fldFlag Then`. Maybe use `While Not rst.EOF` and `rst.MoveNext` to advance through recordset.

Comment: Please read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CmdAssignSTOT_Click()

    'Declarations
    Dim ask As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    'popup message box to confirm save
    ask = MsgBox("Do you want to save new STOT entry?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "System message...") = vbYes

    If ask = True Then
        'initialize value of incrementing variable x
        Set DB = CurrentDb
        Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("STOTCoverageBatchAssigned") 'setting the table

        While Not rst.EOF
            If rst.fldFlag.Value = True Then 'actions below will only be performed when their tickbox fldFlag is ticked.
                With rst 'encoding!
                    .Edit
                        ![STOTNo] = Me.STOTNo
                        ![STOTDate] = Me.STOTDate
                        ![BatchNo] = Me!STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.BatchNo
                        ![PCICCheck] = Me!STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.CompleteDocsPCIC
                        ![ARBCheck] = Me!STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.CompleteDocsARB
                        ![PCICDocsReceivedDate] = Me!STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.PCICDocsReceivedDate
                        ![ARBDocsReceivedDate] = Me!STOTCoverageBatchUnassigned.ARBDocsReceivedDate    
                    .Update
                    .MoveNext
                End With
                Me!STOTNo.Value = Nz(DMax("STOTNo", "tblSTOT"), 0) + 1 'increment STOT number in the STOTNo field  only when actions above have been performed
            End If
        Wend
        rst.Close
    End If
```

It will, however, use the current record only in the subform, which I don't know if what you wish, as it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.
    End Sub